# Number of elements of given order in the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with $o(G)=n$. Suppose $N_d=|\{g\in G: o(g)=d\}|$. Then by Lagrange's theorem we know that $$\sum\limits_{d\mid n}N_d=n.$$

Then using Mobius inversion formula we get the following result: $$N_n=
\sum \limits_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\dfrac{n}{d}.$$

Is it true? If it's false please explain in details where is the mistake?

Would be grateful for help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to apply Möbius inversion with $g(m) = m$ and $f(m) = N_m.$ However, in order to apply Möbius inversion, you must have
$$
g(m) = \sum_{d\mid m} f(d)
$$
for *all* $m\in\Bbb N.$ In particular, this would mean that
$$
m = \sum_{d\mid m}N_d,
$$
even if $m\nmid\# G.$

Now, take any nontrivial $G$ and consider $m = n^2.$ For any $d\mid n^2$ with $d \nmid n,$ we have $N_d = 0.$ Then
$$\sum_{d\mid n^2} N_d = \sum_{d\mid n} N_d + \sum_{d\mid n^2, d \nmid n} N_d= n + 0\neq n^2.$$

Thus, Möbius inversion doesn't apply here!

Here's a concrete counterexample: let $G = S_3.$ Then $N_1 = 1, N_2 = 3,$ and $N_3 = 2.$ However,

$$
\sum_{d\mid 2}\mu(d)\frac{2}{d} = 2\mu(1) + \mu(2) = 2 + (-1) = 1\neq 3 = N_2.
$$